# Is this quote really from the Bhavishya-Purana?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, translation-request, reference-request, reference

I came across a website which said the following quote is from the Bhavishya-Purana.

“In another country a prophet will come along with his companions. His name will be Muhammad and he will appear in a desert country.”

I have looked through the Bhavisya Purana and though I have found the more well known but about Mahamada (where he performs illusions and is killed etc) I couldn't find this quote.

Though I highly doubt it is genuine, I would like to know if it is actually a genuine quote, and if I missed anything.

Comment: Bhavisya purana was written after Islam was born. I won't be surprised if such is written along it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Bhavishya Purana calls Muhammad as the rebirth of demon Tripurasura who deludes people with illusions -

> "There, with the order of Bali dayitya, **the great illusionist
> Tripuraasur got rebirth, whom I have been destroyed, turned him into
> ashes.**  His inner reality is, **he got his rebirth to flourish his
> greatness and spread dynasty of Daityas. His name is ' Mahaamada** ',
> **who is always fond of doing pisacha like works.** Therefore Rajan, please don't stay in this place of paishacha (land of Pathaans), by my
> grace you will be pure."

2. Kalidasa killed him with the blessing of Devi Bhagavati -

> "By that time, Kalidasa got the knowledge of his maya and being red in
> anger said to Mahaamada:-"Wicked you are! **You are deluding king in
> illusion that is your illusion which is not true, therefore I will
> kill you sinner**, the most wretched person of Vahika. saying this the
> Brahman (Kalidasa) started reciting navaarn (navakshari) mantra. He
> recited it ten thousand times. Being pleased with Kalidasa, **Devi
> gave powerful energy into Kalidasa's body and every tenth part of his
> recitation, the enormous energy came out through his body obliterating
> each and every parts of the body of Vahika purusha into fire.** He
> when fully turned into ashes, became god of the Mlecchas."

Chapter 3, Pratisarga Khanda, Bhavishya Purana.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151445/discussion-on-answer-by-gokul-renjith-is-this-quote-really-from-the-bhavishya-pu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.